# $(123)!$ divided by $(25!)^x$. What is the maximum possible integral value of $x$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

The answer given is $5$. But I am getting $4$.

Here is what I have done.
$$25!= 2^{22}\cdot3^{10}\cdot5^6\cdot7^3\cdot11^2\cdot13\cdot17\cdot19\cdot23$$
$$123!=2^{117}\cdot3^{59}\cdot5^{28}\cdot7^{19}\cdot11^{12}\cdot23^5\dots$$

So, the minimum value comes in exponent of five. It would be $\lfloor\frac{28}{6}\rfloor=4$.

What is wrong with this approach?

Comment: 5 is incorrect, you are right.

Comment: Maybe the question wanted $125!$ ?

Comment: By the way, the product of any $25$ consecutive integers is divisible by $25!$, so you can deduce without any prime factorization that the answer is at least $4$.

Comment: $270!$ or $273!$ would give the answer $11$ rather than $10$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\let\leq\leqslant\let\geq\geqslant4$ is correct: it is the largest integer not exceeding the fractions $\frac{\text{exponent of prime p in 123!}}{\text{exponent of prime p in 25!}}$ where $p$ runs through the prime divisors of $25!$.
The minimal fraction is attained when $p=5$, giving $\frac{28}6$, so $x\leq4$ and $x=4$ works.